# Algebraic Riccati equation (DARE) stabilazability condition

Tags: optimization, notation, matlab, matrix-equations, optimal-control

I'm Trying to help in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521251/a-system-of-matrix-equations-2-riccati-1-lyapunov/1568457?noredirect=1#comment3193362_1568457) which involves [Algebraic Ricatti equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation). Honestly to say I never met this equation before.

I'm struggling to understand the conditions stated in the limitations of the [`dare`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dare.html?searchHighlight=dare) algorithm in matlab. For convinience I quote it here:

> The $(A, B)$ pair must be stabilizable (that is, all eigenvalues of
>   $A$ outside the unit disk must be controllable). In addition, the
>   associated symplectic pencil must have no eigenvalue on the unit
>   circle. Sufficient conditions for this to hold are $(Q, A)$ detectable
>   when $S = 0$ and $R > 0$, or $$\begin{bmatrix} Q & S \\ S^T & R \end{bmatrix}>0$$

All $A,B,S$ are matrices ($S=0$ in my case ), so I don't understand how a matrix can be greater then zero? Is this is special notations for positive definite matrix?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a notation for positive definite matrix. Several works use this $>$ instead of $\succ$. In the context of control theory both notations mean the same thing.

Comment: are you familiar with $dare$ by mistake? I tried to create  random  $R,Q$ with eigenvalues $>0$ together with controllable $(A, B)$ but $dare$ still fails $70\%$ of times which make me craze:( Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try making sure they are symmetric. It could help the solver.

Comment: look at the code under the link in the question please. It missing the part where I make sure the eigenvalues are positive, but for this part I do something very stupid-simple like stay in a loop until it so.